# Instantiating Workbook / excel object in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015.  I have 750 csv files in a folder.  I need to delete certain columns in them (where there is an asterisk).  I made a project wpf application to do that when user chooses that option on a dialogue box.  Below is the code that is activated on the button click.

```
Class MainWindow
Dim xl As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application
Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook
Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim strName As String
Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String

Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    If cleanRadioButton.IsChecked = True Then
        strPath = "c:\test\old\"
        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
        Do While strFile <> ""

            wb = wb.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)

            'Loop through the sheets.
            For iIndex = 1 To xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                ws = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(iIndex)

                'Loop through the columns.
                For iCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                    'Check row 1 of this column for the char of *
                    If InStr(ws.Cells(10, iCol).Value, "*") > 0 Then
                        'We have found a column with the char of *
                        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
                        ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                        ws.Columns(iCol + 1).EntireColumn.Delete
                        ws.Columns(iCol + 2).EntireColumn.Delete
                    End If
                Next iCol

            Next iIndex
            wb.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\test\new\" & wb.Name, FileFormat:=51)
            wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            strFile = Dir()

        Loop

        MessageBox.Show("The csv files have now been cleaned.  Congrats.")
    Else inputRadioButton.IsChecked = True
        MessageBox.Show("The data has now been split into Trajectory and ForcePlate input files.  High 5.")
    End If
End Sub End Class
```

I get no errors on compiling but when running i get a NullReferenceException was unhandled at line `wb = wb.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)`.  This is because wb is null and has not been instantiated i believe.  I can't work out how to do it though as you can't use the New keyword on an interface...

Can someone please explain?? 
thx

Comment: `Open` is not a method of the `Workbook` object, but of the `Workbooks` object. So you need something like: `wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)

Comment: This is VB.NET, not VBA. Plus, I don't see any instance of `wb`. It is declared on top, but never set as `New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you responses.  Rory was correct - WorkbookS is the object not Workbook to call Open.

Matteo NNZ was also correct in a way.  Here is the code that actually worked for me (key was in the Imports statement, and to set Embed Interop Types = FALSE in the references properties for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Class MainWindow
    Dim xl As Excel.Application = New Excel.ApplicationClass()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim strName As String
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

```
Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    If cleanRadioButton.IsChecked = True Then
        strPath = "c:\test\old\"
        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)

            'Loop through the sheets.
            For iIndex = 1 To xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                ws = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(iIndex)

                'Loop through the columns.
                For iCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                    'Check row 10 of this column for the char of *
                    If InStr(ws.Cells(10, iCol).Value, "*") > 0 Then
                        'We have found a column with the char of *
                        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
                        ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                        ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                        ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                        iCol = iCol - 3
                    End If
                Next iCol

            Next iIndex
            wb.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\test\new\" & wb.Name, FileFormat:=51)
            wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            strFile = Dir()

        Loop

        MessageBox.Show("The csv files have now been cleaned.  Congrats.")
    Else inputRadioButton.IsChecked = True
        MessageBox.Show("The data has now been split into Trajectory and ForcePlate input files.  High 5.")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Hope that helps the next person
solution:
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Dim xl As Excel.Application = New Excel.ApplicationClass()